# Storing a DateTime value of DateTime.MinValue in azure table storage fails

Tags: azure-table-storage

I am getting an aggregated exception while storing a `DateTime` value of either `null` or `DateTime.MinValue`. How do I store an acceptable default `DateTime` value in Azure table store?

Comment: Could you share more details on this question? For example, the exception string, the inner exception, how were you using DateTime.MinValue in Azure Table by code?

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft You just get a 400 Bad Request exception, with no additional details.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model#property-types):

> Edm.DateTime DateTime A 64-bit value expressed as Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC). The supported DateTime range begins from 12:00
>   midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.), UTC. The range ends at December
>   31, 9999.

So, the minimum .Net DateTime value you can store in Azure Tables is `new DateTime(1601, 1, 1)`.

But DateTime.MinValue is equal to `new DateTime(0001, 01, 01)`, that's why you can't store it.

2. null should be ok, if your date time property type is nullable `(DateTime?)`.

Comment: this worked for me: ```new DateTime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)```, but using null is better IMHO